# Finding the mean of consecutive columns

Tags: python, pandas, mean, rolling-computation

I have a very large data file (tens of thousands of rows and columns) formatted similarly to this.

```
name   x  y gh_00hr_bio_rep1 gh_00hr_bio_rep2 gh_00hr_bio_rep3 gh_06hr_bio_rep1
gene1  x  y         2               3               2               1
gene2  x  y         5               7               6               2
```

My goal for each gene is to find the mean of each set of repetitions.

At the end I would like to only have columns of mean values titled something like "00hr_bio" and delete all the individual repetitions.

My thinking right now is to use something like this:

```
for row in df:
    df[avg] = df.iloc[3:].rolling(window=3, axis=1).mean()
```

But I have no idea how to actually make this work.

The `df.iloc[3]` is my way of trying to start from the 3rd column but I am fairly certain doing it this way does not work.

I don't even know where to begin in terms of "merging" the 3 columns into only 1.

Any suggestions you have will be greatly appreciated as I obviously have no idea what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first build a Series of final names indexed by the original columns:

```
names = pd.Series(['_'.join(i.split('_')[:-1]) for i in df.columns[3:]],
                  index = df.columns[3:])
```

I would then use it to ask a mean of a groupby on axis 1:

```
tmp = df.iloc[:, 3:].groupby(names, axis=1).agg('mean')
```

It gives a new dataframe indexed like the original one and having the averaged columns:

```
   gh_00hr_bio  gh_06hr_bio
0     2.333333          1.0
1     6.000000          2.0
```

You can then horizontally concat it to the first dataframe or to its 3 first columns:

```
result = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :3], tmp], axis=1)
```

to get:

```
    name  x  y  gh_00hr_bio  gh_06hr_bio
0  gene1  x  y     2.333333          1.0
1  gene2  x  y     6.000000          2.0
```

Comment: Okay plot twist, in the larger dataset some of the columns have a different number of replicates ranging from 1-4. How would you make this work for all columns, regardless of repetition number? I was thinking about seeing if the column names before rep_ match eachother, but I am not sure how to go about doin that.

Comment: @keenan: this should not depend on the number of replicates because they are grouped *according to the relevant part* stored in the `names` Series.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close.

```
df['avg'] = df.iloc[:, 2:].mean(axis=1)
```

will get you this:

```
       x  y  gh_00hr_bio_rep1  gh_00hr_bio_rep2  gh_00hr_bio_rep3  gh_06hr_bio_rep1  avg
gene1  x  y                 2                 3                 2                 1  2.0
gene2  x  y                 5                 7                 6                 2  5.0
```

If you wish to get the mean from different sets of columns, you could do something like this:

```
for col in range(10):
    df['avg%i' % col] = df.iloc[:, 2+col*5:7+col*5].mean(axis=1)
```

If you have the same number of columns per average. Otherwise you'd probably want to use the name of the rep columns, depending on what your data looks like.

Comment: How would I apply this function to multiple columns at once? I have over 1000 more sets of 3s that I need to find the mean for. I don't mind if I create a bunch of avg columns and then delete the individual repetitions later, but for each 'set' I would need a way to change the name of the avg column as the column is created so I can tell them apart ('gh_00hr_bio_avg'  'gh_06hr_bio_avg' ect)